# Prove $S$ closed for $S$ subset of $[0,1]$ whose decimal expansions can be written without a $4$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I am trying to prove the question in the title and was wondering if someone could look it over. I'm not 100% sure it is okay.

> Prove $S$ is closed. Let $S$ be a subset of $[0,1]$ whose decimal expansions can be written without a $4$

Let $x \in S^c$. Then $x$ has a decimal expansion $x = 0.d_1d_2\dots d_{n-1}d_nd_{n+1}$ where $d_n = 4$ and $n$ is the first such integer where $d_n = 4$.

All of the digits after $d_n$ cannot be 0 otherwise we would have:

$x = 0.d_1d_2\dots d_{n-1}40000\dots = 0.d_1d_2\dots d_{n-1}39999\dots$ and we could write $x$ without a $4$.

Likewise, all of the digits after $d_n$ cannot be $9$ otherwise we would have:

$x = 0.d_1d_2\dots d_{n-1}49999\dots = 0.d_1d_2\dots d_{n-1}50000\dots$ and we could write $x$ without a $4$.

Thus, we have that:

$a = 0.d_1d_2\dots d_{n-1}4000\dots < x < 0.d_1d_2\dots d_{n-1}5000\dots = b$.

Thus, if $x \in (a, b)$ it must have the form:

$x = 0.d_1d_2\dots d_{n-1}d_nd_{n+1}$ where $d_n = 4$ and $n$ is the first such integer where $d_n = 4$.

So for arbitrary $x \in S^c$ we have shown there is an open interval $(a, b)$ where all $x \in (a, b) \in S^c$. In other words, $\forall x \in S^c$ there is a ball $B(x, \epsilon)$ for $\epsilon = \frac{10^{-(n+1)}}{2}.$ Hence, $S^c$ is open and $S$ is closed.

Comment: I don't find any mistake. Is there any point about which you are partucularly uncertain?

Comment: I'm just uncertain that it is sufficient/my choice of $\epsilon$ is ok?